# How can I push data to array when using mapping (address => address[]) mappingName?

Tags: solidity, addresses, arrays, mapping

What is the exact syntax to push data using the above given syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do as follow:

```
mapping(address=>address[]) addressToMany;
        
function addAddress(address _address) public {
  addressToMany[msg.sender].push(_address);
}
```

Comment: It worked for my contract perfectly. There is another query related to this, is how to delete data/pop data after pushing it to an array.

Comment: @Rudrika You're welcome :). 
To delete the data you can use the `delete` statement as follow: `delete array[index];`

Comment: I am working with double mapping and address => address[] mapping.

Comment: I am working with double mapping and address => address[] mapping. Where in first mapping I am storing every address who belongs to one common address using double mapping. And now I am storing those addresses in one array using the above-given solution. The problem is here I am not able to identify indexes of array.  `myAddressMapping[commonAddress][subAddresses]` and I want to delete that particular `subAddress` which has 0 balance.

Comment: @Rudrika If I understand correctly, you want to delete the address which has 0 as balance.
You can do a for loop and search for it as following:
`for(uint i = 0; i < addressToMany[msg.sender].length; i++){
 // if statement to check if address has balance 0

 delete addressToMany[msg.sender][i]`

Comment: Alright...! Let me check..!

Comment: Yes, it worked for me! Thank you for the solution!